# What's happening in TryUpdateModelAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

So I'm doing this [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud) on ASP.NET Core with EF 6 and it just went through updating a model through the edit-controller.

There is this piece of code that have me really confused that I imagine (and perhaps hope) isn't as confusing to a lot of you.

```
var studentToUpdate = await _context.Students.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ID == id);

if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
          studentToUpdate, 
          "", 
           s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate))
// goes on to save the context
```

So, the only thing this controller takes as parameter is the `int id` and that's how it gets a hold of the `studentToUpdate`. What I'm not entirely familiar with here, is where does it get the update-values from?

What I know:

- `TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>`

  - first argument: model to update
  - second argument: prefix (?) from reference: *The prefix to use when looking up values in the .*
  - third argument: a linq-statement which I suspect is related to the solution I'm looking for.
- Ran the debugger and before the function was executed `studentToUpdate.FirstMidNames` was `Carson`(original) but after the function had been executed it was `Carsey`(new). The string `Carsey` was always in the this>Request>Form>Results View (which held a list of all the values from the form).

So I understand that the `TryUpdateModelAsync` function somehow uses the linq-statement and the form-result to get the new values for `studentToUpdate`, but I really don't see how and where it does this?

Comment: it does this via model binding. That topic in itself it too broad to answer here. For more information about model binding, see the model binding article -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

Comment: Thank you! I'll read up on it

Comment: @Nkosi So the link statement is querying the form values? Binding them to s, which in turn is used to update studentToUpdate?

Comment: put a little differently, it uses lambda expressions to know which properties to look for in the route values and on the model. It will take those values and update the model.

Comment: @Nkosi Ah thank you! I didn't recognize it for a lambda expression. I'm new to ASP.NET and thought the expressions using => was what people were referring to as linq-queries.

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L1973

Comment: Im also wondering what the point of the prefix ist. In your example it is an empty string. I had to use the name of the binding variable to make it work. Also why does it use a string type for that?

Comment: The prefix parameter is somewhat explained in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#complex-types

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without going into too much technical details. The call to `TryUpdateModelAsync` in the provided example

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
      studentToUpdate, 
      "", 
       s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate)){
    //...
}
```

Updates the specified `Student` instance `studentToUpdate` using values from the controller's current `ControllerContext`, which would have been populated with data provided in the request.  It uses lambda expression(s) which represent top-level properties which need to be included for the current model when trying the update. It will take only the values of those properties and update the model.

So in the above example even if the entire model was provided by the form it will only update the `FirstMidName`, `LastName`, and `EnrollmentDate` on the specified instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most confusing thing about this is Third argument: a linq-statement.

Every linQ expression [`i => i.property`] will match with each column inside table or the constraint (Foreign Key, Index,...) (what we know as navigation properties in EF MVC).

So, Third argument decides what should be updated (async) to the Datebase. And it does this via model binding [Link to model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0)